# Unable to get the value of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio-button

I am not able to get second and third radio buttons values.
my code just gives me the first radio button value when I select this.

this is my radio buttons and the function by which I want to store the value of the radio button.

```
<input type="radio" id="choiced" name="Q0_choice" value="one">
<input type="radio" id="choiced" name="Q0_choice" value="2">
<input type="radio" id="choiced" name="Q0_choice" value="iii">



next.onclick = function () {
    if (document.getElementById('choiced').checked) {
        ans = document.getElementById('choiced').value;
    }
}
```

Comment: but when I select second and third radio button it didn't give me values of these.

Answer (score 0):

This is because ID values must be unique - so it's grabbing the first element on the page it finds with the ID of `choiced`. You'll want to give each a unique ID, and you can use the `name` attribute for grouping radio button. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: it gives me undefined when I try.                 ans = document.getElementsByName('Q0_choice').value;

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.querySelector('#choiced:checked')
```

This query return checked radio button.

Comment: when I alert the ans variable it gives me. this page says [object HTMLInputElement]

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the same ID for those inputs:

```
<input type="radio" id="choiced" name="Q0_choice" value="one">
<input type="radio" id="choiced2" name="Q0_choice" value="2">
<input type="radio" id="choiced3" name="Q0_choice" value="iii">
```

Then to get the selected you have to get them by it's `name` property. You can loop to check which one is selected.

```
next.onclick = function () {
    const radios = document.getElementsByName('Q0_choice');
    radios.forEach((radio) => {
        if (radio.checked){
          console.log(radio.value);
        }
    })
}
```